# Editar columnas de un DataGridView con un TextBox c#

Tags: c#, datagrid, textbox

Como puedo hacer que al poner yo una cantidad en el TextBox que esta abajo de Tirar Completo, esa misma cantidad se refle en Cantidad pero que esta en el DataGridView pero en todas las columnas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo del DataGridView

```
    public void buscarModulos()
    {
        try
        {
            SqlDataAdapter datos = new SqlDataAdapter("select c.id_parteM,describpM,precio,bom from modelo_modulos a inner join union_modulos b on a.id_modeloM = b.id_modeloM inner join partes_modulos c on b.id_parteM = c.id_parteM where a.id_modeloM ='" + txtBuscar.Text + "'", conexion.abrirConexion());
            DataSet sd = new DataSet();
            datos.Fill(sd, "modelo_modulos");
            this.dataGridView1.DataSource = sd.Tables[0];
            this.dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;/*Para que se ajusten las columnas al ancho del DataGridView*/
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 70;
            dataGridView1.Columns[2].Width = 220;
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Numero de Parte";
            dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Descripcion";
            dataGridView1.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Precio";
            dataGridView1.Columns[4].HeaderText = "BOM";
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].ReadOnly = false;
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].ReadOnly = true;
            dataGridView1.Columns[2].ReadOnly = true;
            dataGridView1.Columns[3].ReadOnly = true;
            dataGridView1.Columns[4].ReadOnly = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].HeaderCell.Value = (1 + i).ToString();
            }
            comando.Connection = conexion.abrirConexion();
            comando.CommandText = "select a.describeM from modelo_modulos a inner join union_modulos b on a.id_modeloM = b.id_modeloM inner join partes_modulos c on b.id_parteM = c.id_parteM where a.id_modeloM ='" + txtBuscar.Text + "'";
            SqlDataReader rd = comando.ExecuteReader();
            lblDescripcion.Text = "";
            if (rd.Read())
            {
                lblDescripcion.Text = rd["describeM"] as string;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ingrese bien el numero del modelo");
        }

        comando.Connection = conexion.cerrarConexion();
    }
```

Comment: Tienes en el código que muestras un bucle `for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)`. Has probado a usar lo mismo para obtener cada una de las filas y modificar la columna `Cantidad` con el valor del textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que crear un evento para el TextBox para cuando cambie el texto o con una tecla especifica se habilite, posteriormente es necesario crear un ciclo como el siguiente:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
  dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cell[1].Value = NombreDelTextBox.Text;
}
```